# SQL give number for each category column

Tags: sql, sql-server

we have table car with

| CAR Type | Colour |
| --- | --- |
| Porsche | Red |
| Porsche | Blue |
| Mercedes | Yellow |
| VW | Yellow |
| VW | RED |

i need this following output:
for each new car type we need a new id

| ID | CAR Type | Colour |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Porsche | Red |
| 1 | Porsche | Blue |
| 2 | Mercedes | Yellow |
| 3 | VW | Yellow |
| 3 | VW | RED |

expect the output like described

Comment: Try `row_number`

Comment: One way is to create a new table with an autoincrement column, then insert all unique values of the Car Type into it. By doing that they will be assigned unique IDs, and you can use this table to normalize your data.

Comment: What defines the order of your data? Why is M after P but before V?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the window function `dense_rank()` :

```
select dense_rank() over (order by [CAR Type]) as ID, *
from mytable
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @table TABLE
(
    CarType NVARCHAR(50),
    Colour NVARCHAR(10)
)

INSERT INTO @table VALUES('Porsche','Red'),
('Porsche','Blue'),
('Mercedes','Yellow'),
('VW','Yellow'),
('VW','RED'),
('VW','White')

SELECT 
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CARTYPE) AS AutoID,
DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY CARTYPE) AS ID,
* FROM @table
```

> Output

[image]

- `AutoID` will be increased automatically
- `ID` will depend on the `CARTYPE` if it's the same then the same number else a new number will allocate to the next rows.

Answer (score 0):

Try DENSE_RANK() function

```
CREATE TABLE TT2
(
    RowNumber INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    CarType NVARCHAR(50),
    Colour NVARCHAR(10)
)

INSERT INTO TT2 VALUES('Porsche','Red'),
('Porsche','Blue'),
('Mercedes','Yellow'),
('VW','Yellow'),
('VW','RED'),
('VW','White')

Select dense_rank() over (order by cartype) AS ID,* from TT2


OUTPUT:
ID  RowNumber   CarType     Colour
1      3        Mercedes    Yellow
2      1        Porsche     Red
2      2        Porsche     Blue
3      4        VW          Yellow
3      5        VW          RED
3      6        VW          White
```